# Tweepy - Differences with status info delivered by Twitter API

Tags: twitter, tweepy

Does somebody knows why Twitter API delivers different information for the same status using different methods?

I'm working on a Twitter bot to collect transit events. I'm facing some issues with the information delivered by the API, due to I've identified that depending on the method, the API can deliver different result for the same Tweet/status.
Here an example for the Tweet ID:1531517617562951682 using api.get_status, the status doesn't have the attributes extended_tweet and timestamp_ms.

Thanks in advance.

```
{
   "created_at": "Tue May 31 06:07:08 +0000 2022",
   "id": 1531517617562951682,
   "id_str": "**1531517617562951682**",
   "text": "01:07 #Precauci\u00f3nVial | Por percance en Av. Ing. Eduardo Molina a la altura de Av. Talism\u00e1n, col. San Pedro el Chic\u2026 (**removed_url)",
   **"truncated": true**,
   "entities": {
      "hashtags": [
         {
            "text": "Precauci\u00f3nVial",
            "indices": [
               6,
               21
            ]
         }
      ],
      "symbols": [],
      "user_mentions": [],
      "urls": [
         {
            "url": **removed_url_short,
            "expanded_url": ,
            "display_url": ,
            "indices": [
               117,
               140
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   "source": "<a href=\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web App</a>",
   "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
   "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
   "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
   "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
   "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
   "user": {
      "id": 166594238,
      "id_str": "166594238",
      "name": "OVIAL_SSCCDMX",
      "screen_name": "OVIALCDMX",
      "location": "Liverpool #136, Col. Ju\u00e1rez",
      "description": "Centro de  Orientaci\u00f3n Vial de la Secretar\u00eda de Seguridad Ciudadana de la Ciudad de M\u00e9xico.",
      "url":,
      "entities": {
         "url": {
            "urls": [
               {
                  "url": ,
                  "expanded_url": ,
                  "display_url": "ssc.cdmx.gob.mx",
                  "indices": [
                     0,
                     23
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         "description": {
            "urls": []
         }
      },
      "protected": false,
      "followers_count": 1866313,
      "friends_count": 125,
      "listed_count": 4188,
      "created_at": "Wed Jul 14 15:00:43 +0000 2010",
      "favourites_count": 2748,
      "utc_offset": null,
      "time_zone": null,
      "geo_enabled": true,
      "verified": true,
      "statuses_count": 1110675,
      "lang": null,
      "contributors_enabled": false,
      "is_translator": false,
      "is_translation_enabled": false,
      "profile_background_color": "000000",
      "profile_background_image_url": 
      "profile_background_image_url_https": ,
      "profile_background_tile": false,
      "profile_image_url": ,
      "profile_image_url_https": ,
      "profile_banner_url": ,
      "profile_link_color": "BC8F8F",
      "profile_sidebar_border_color": "000000",
      "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "000000",
      "profile_text_color": "000000",
      "profile_use_background_image": false,
      "has_extended_profile": false,
      "default_profile": false,
      "default_profile_image": false,
      "following": false,
      "follow_request_sent": false,
      "notifications": false,
      "translator_type": "none",
      "withheld_in_countries": []
   },
   "geo": null,
   "coordinates": null,
   "place": null,
   "contributors": null,
   "is_quote_status": false,
   "retweet_count": 0,
   "favorite_count": 0,
   "favorited": false,
   "retweeted": false,
   "possibly_sensitive": false,
   "possibly_sensitive_appealable": false,
   "lang": "es"
}
```

Same status collected with a stream.Attributes extended_tweet and timestamp are present on the status:

```
{
   "created_at": "Tue May 31 06:07:08 +0000 2022",
   "id": 1531517617562951682,
   "id_str": "1531517617562951682",
   "text": "01:07 #Precauci\u00f3nVial | Por percance en Av. Ing. Eduardo Molina a la altura de Av. Talism\u00e1n, col. San Pedro el Chic\u2026 (**removed url)",
   "display_text_range": [
      0,
      140
   ],
   "source": "<a href=\"" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web App</a>",
   "truncated": true,
   "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
   "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
   "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
   "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
   "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
   "user": {
      "id": 166594238,
      "id_str": "166594238",
      "name": "OVIAL_SSCCDMX",
      "screen_name": "OVIALCDMX",
      "location": "Liverpool #136, Col. Ju\u00e1rez",
      "url": "http://ssc.cdmx.gob.mx",
      "description": "Centro de  Orientaci\u00f3n Vial de la Secretar\u00eda de Seguridad Ciudadana de la Ciudad de M\u00e9xico.",
      "translator_type": "none",
      "protected": false,
      "verified": true,
      "followers_count": 1866203,
      "friends_count": 125,
      "listed_count": 4188,
      "favourites_count": 2748,
      "statuses_count": 1110325,
      "created_at": "Wed Jul 14 15:00:43 +0000 2010",
      "utc_offset": null,
      "time_zone": null,
      "geo_enabled": true,
      "lang": null,
      "contributors_enabled": false,
      "is_translator": false,
      "profile_background_color": "000000",
      "profile_background_image_url": ,
      "profile_background_image_url_https": ,
      "profile_background_tile": false,
      "profile_link_color": "BC8F8F",
      "profile_sidebar_border_color": "000000",
      "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "000000",
      "profile_text_color": "000000",
      "profile_use_background_image": false,
      "profile_image_url": ,
      "profile_image_url_https": ,
      "profile_banner_url": ,
      "default_profile": false,
      "default_profile_image": false,
      "following": null,
      "follow_request_sent": null,
      "notifications": null,
      "withheld_in_countries": []
   },
   "geo": null,
   "coordinates": null,
   "place": null,
   "contributors": null,
   "is_quote_status": false,
   "extended_tweet": {
      "full_text": "01:07 #Precauci\u00f3nVial | Por percance en Av. Ing. Eduardo Molina a la altura de Av. Talism\u00e1n, col. San Pedro el Chico, servicios de emergencia acuden al lugar. (**removed url)",
      "display_text_range": [
         0,
         158
      ],
      "entities": {
         "hashtags": [
            {
               "text": "Precauci\u00f3nVial",
               "indices": [
                  6,
                  21
               ]
            }
         ],
         "urls": [],
         "user_mentions": [],
         "symbols": [],
         "media": [
            {
               "id": 1531517217703092224,
               "id_str": "1531517217703092224",
               "indices": [
                  159,
                  182
               ],
               "additional_media_info": {
                  "monetizable": false
               },
               "media_url": ,
               "media_url_https": ,
               "url":,
               "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/q3seKvyPIM",
               "expanded_url": ,
               "type": "video",
               "video_info": {
                  "aspect_ratio": [
                     16,
                     9
                  ],
                  "duration_millis": 4003,
                  "variants": [
                     {
                        "content_type": "application/x-mpegURL",
                        "url": ""
                     },
                     {
                        "bitrate": 832000,
                        "content_type": "video/mp4",
                        "url": "
                     },
                     {
                        "bitrate": 256000,
                        "content_type": "video/mp4",
                        "url": 
                     }
                  ]
               },
               "sizes": {
                  "thumb": {
                     "w": 150,
                     "h": 150,
                     "resize": "crop"
                  },
                  "large": {
                     "w": 640,
                     "h": 360,
                     "resize": "fit"
                  },
                  "medium": {
                     "w": 640,
                     "h": 360,
                     "resize": "fit"
                  },
                  "small": {
                     "w": 640,
                     "h": 360,
                     "resize": "fit"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "extended_entities": {
         "media": [
            {
               "id": 1531517217703092224,
               "id_str": "1531517217703092224",
               "indices": [
                  159,
                  182
               ],
               "additional_media_info": {
                  "monetizable": false
               },
               "media_url": ,
               "media_url_https": ,
               "url": ,
               "display_url": ,
               "expanded_url": ,
               "type": "video",
               "video_info": {
                  "aspect_ratio": [
                     16,
                     9
                  ],
                  "duration_millis": 4003,
                  "variants": [
                     {
                        "content_type": "application/x-mpegURL",
                        "url": "
                     },
                     {
                        "bitrate": 832000,
                        "content_type": "video/mp4",
                        "url": "
                     },
                     {
                        "bitrate": 256000,
                        "content_type": "video/mp4",
                        "url": ""
                     }
                  ]
               },
               "sizes": {
                  "thumb": {
                     "w": 150,
                     "h": 150,
                     "resize": "crop"
                  },
                  "large": {
                     "w": 640,
                     "h": 360,
                     "resize": "fit"
                  },
                  "medium": {
                     "w": 640,
                     "h": 360,
                     "resize": "fit"
                  },
                  "small": {
                     "w": 640,
                     "h": 360,
                     "resize": "fit"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "quote_count": 0,
   "reply_count": 0,
   "retweet_count": 0,
   "favorite_count": 0,
   "entities": {
      "hashtags": [
         {
            "text": "Precauci\u00f3nVial",
            "indices": [
               6,
               21
            ]
         }
      ],
      "urls": [
         {
            "url": ,
            "expanded_url": ,
            "display_url": "twitter.com/i/web/status/1\u2026",
            "indices": [
               117,
               140
            ]
         }
      ],
      "user_mentions": [],
      "symbols": []
   },
   "favorited": false,
   "retweeted": false,
   "possibly_sensitive": false,
   "filter_level": "low",
   "lang": "es",
   "**timestamp_ms**": "1653977228905"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For v1.1, the extended Tweet information is available by default in the streaming API, but for the REST endpoints, you need to add the `tweet_mode=extended` parameter to your request to retrieve the full text.

In V2, there is no longer a concept of extended (beyond 140 characters) Tweets. All Tweets are natively up to 280 characters as standard.